# Writing to password protected NFC tag in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, core-nfc

Is there a way in Swift (NFC core) to remove and set password on the tag. I am currently doing a research on the web but I cannot find anything, only simple read write code snippets.

I guess there is a way, so if somebody could point me in the right direction, or give me some hits on how it can be done.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what tag are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think that isn't available now in CoreNFC and don't be available in future. Me too doing this research and found only availability to do tag readOnly by using WriteLock. But that operation irreversible as i know. If you found something else, please write here.

But I think it depends on the chip used in the tag. Because Ukrainian Passports using some PIN and CAN codes for access to data inside the tag. And I have application, but I don't know it writes by Swift or not.